# Erro ao publicar Site

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis

O Sistema tava funcionando muito bem, fiz algumas alterações e depois que que subi pro servidor ocorre esse erro, alguém sabe me dizer o que seria ? O sistema é MVC com VS 2013.

Obs.: Voltei a versão anterior que era um backup do site e continua o erro.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Adicionei a tag: `<customErrors mode="Off" />`

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: coloca o customError Off para poder ver o erro que esta dando

Comment: ocorreu algum erro na execução do site no servidor remoto, segue as instruções da imagem (colocar customErrors off) para ver o erro real

Comment: Adicionei a tag `<customErrors mode="Off" />` e adicionei o print na pergunta

Comment: Parece ser um erro no assembly desse Pechkin , tem como vc tentar subir a dll dele de novo ?

Comment: 2) Tem como testar remover a referência da dll ? Também achei isso [link] https://github.com/gmanny/Pechkin/tree/master/Pechkin/tools/net40

Comment: acabei de subir... mas continua o msm erro

Comment: @AdrianoCordeiro post o erro e não as imagens. Texto fica melhor pra indexação e busca de alguém que possa vim pesquisar sobre.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possívelmente isso vai resolver seu problema :

```
1)Seleciona no IIS o pool do seu site
2)Clica com o botao direito 
3)Seleciona Advanced Settings 
4)Seleciona TRUE em Enable 32-bit Applications.
```

Se o item **4)** não estiver habilitado com certeza vc vai receber o erro que está descrevendo

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Não dando certo :

Instalei o Pechkin aqui e detectei as seguintes dependencias :

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Pra tentar resolver eu tentaria :

1)Subir todos esses arquivos novamente

2) Deletar todos esses arquivos , remover as referencias de Common.Logging.dll e Pechkin.dll e instalar novamente pelo nuget , compilar o projeto e subir novamente essas dlls + web.config + a dll do seu projeto

Comment: Diego estava tudo funcionando corretamente antes de subir os arquivos via FTP e depois apareceu o erro, eu não tenho acesso ao IIS, mas vou falar com o cliente para verificar essa configuração.

Comment: vo fazer uma edição com uma segunda possível solução

Comment: Resolvido, @Diego Valadares o problema é que a dll _Pechkin.dll estava salva em dois lugares: na raiz do projeto e também estava salva na pasta **bin**, por isso que o projeto depois de compilado perdeu a referência, eu não havia notado isso, não havia notado porque em tempo de projeto o problema não ocorre.

Comment: Que massa que o problema foi resolvido @AdrianoSUV ! Já tava ficando encucado com o que poderia ser tbm  e como não dava pra saber exatamente qual dependência tava causando o problema acho que a solução era mesmo na base das tentativas .